# Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd

Tags: python, pip, spyder, xlrd

i am having difficulties with an errorcode that i can't solve in Sypder/Python.

`ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.`

in order to solve this problem i have read other posts related to this topic and tried the following:

`!pip install xlrd`

then this popped up: Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\sehoon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)

However, once i ran the code, the same error code appeared.

I also tried the simple one like: `pip install xlrd` and  `pip install --upgrade pip`.
running the code after the implementation
It showed: `Note:you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.`
The result was the same -  ImportError

Any advice?

Comment: Is "xlrd" installed in the same environment as pandas?

Run "pip show pandas" and "pip show xlrd" and check if they are installed in the same environment.

Comment: @Bee thanks for your remarks. Yes, i did check their location. They are installed in the same environment